# How to make the java program not to accept any negative values

Tags: java

I have made a program but I am having trouble with the `if/else` statement.

The program is not supposed to accept any negative values, but it does not step out of the loop when a negative value is entered. The code snippet is:

```
try {
    System.out.println("Enter the number of numbers to add.");
    int n_nos1=Integer.parseInt(bx.readLine());
    double add=0,sub=0,pro=1,div=1;
    if(n_nos1!=0 && n_nos1>0)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the number(s)");
        for(int i=1;i<=n_nos1;i++)
        {
            double t=Double.parseDouble(bx.readLine());
            add+=t;
        }
    }
    else System.out.println("Either zero was entered or an invalid character was entered");
}
```

I have put the catch statement down. The trouble I am having here is that it still accepts the negative values.

Comment: You aren't checking if it is a negative number inside the loop, you are checking outside of it, so you won't break out. Change it so you check inside the loop.

Comment: You are only checking the number of numbers is not positive.  You are not check each value as well.

Comment: So, `n_nos1` has to be an integer greater than 0. That makes sense. What should happen if `t` is negative? Ignore it and ask again? Terminate the run? Display the sum so far and ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change

```
add+=t;
```

to

```
add += t < 0 ? 0 : t;
```

if `t` is below `0` then just add `0` to `add`, otherwise add `t`

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Enter the number(s)");
for(int i=1;i<=n_nos1;i++)
{
    double t=Double.parseDouble(bx.readLine());
    //add this piece of code
    if(t < 0)
    {
        break;
    }
    add+=t;
}
```

Comment: so first a if(n_nos!=0) then a second if() statement that u have said?

Comment: Have your whole program as is and add in the if statement after your readline.
if( t < 0 ){
   break;
}
Here's where your logic break.
Your first checks for negative number and when one is enter, it goes into the else. This is perfect, but when a positive number is enter, it goes into a loop of collecting numbers. In this loop it never checks for negative number. If you add a negative checker (if statement) inside, you can do whatever you want within that if statement. Add a message that the person enter a negative number and break out of the loop or something else.